# What actually is loaded into RAM when you run a program?

Tags: operating-system

What actually is loaded into RAM when you run a program for that particular process?

Comment: A subset of whatever is specified in the header of the executable file.  Not clear what you are asking...?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a program, the executable itself and its associated resources like images, dlls and other modules needed by executable are loaded into RAM. For example when you open an image from an executable, both executable and image are loaded into RAM.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of oversimplification, in modern systems little gets loaded into RAM when you run a program. The program loader reads the executable file and follows the instructions it contains to map the various pages to files.

As the program starts running, it generates page faults when it needs memory for the first time and the operating system loads the data from disk as needed.